# Print a sentence saying the day of the year using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am trying to write this using SQL SERVER:

> "Hi! Today is ... This is the day number... of the year. New year's eve is in ... days".

My code runs with no problem but I can't print as well. What am I doing wrong? I haven't finished the whole phrase because I need to fix the problem before I get to the last part.

```
DECLARE
    @currentDate DateTime
        SET @currentDate = GETDATE();

DECLARE @dayofyear datetime
SET @dayofyear=DATEDIFF(day,STR(YEAR(@dayofyear),4)+'0101',@dayofyear)+1
-- SELECT Numbertoday = DATEDIFF(day,STR(YEAR(@dayofyear),4)+'0101',@dayofyear)+1

print('Hi! Today is '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @currentDate , 111) + '. ' + 'This is the day number '+ ' ' +  CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), @dayofyear) + of the year.')
```

Comment: Which database? SQL server from the looks of it?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, you can use `concat()`

**Example**

```
Print concat('Hi! Today is '
           ,format(GetDate(),'dddd, MMM d, yyyy.')
           ,'  This is the day number '
           ,DateDiff(DAY,datename(YEAR,getdate())+'0101',getdate()) + 1
           ,' of the year.'
           )
```

**Results**

```
Hi! Today is Thursday, Jul 4, 2019.  This is the day number 185 of the year.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do is:

```
    declare @today varchar(11) = convert(varchar(11), getdate(), 1);

    declare @dayOfTheYear int = datepart(DAYOFYEAR, getdate());

    declare @untilNewYearsEve int = datepart(dayofyear, datefromparts(year(getdate()), 12, 31)) - @dayOfTheYear

   -- if you use print, you should see the result under the 'messages' tab not in the 'results' tab in SSMS
    print 'Hi! Today is '+ @today + '. ' + 'This is the day number '+ cast( @dayOfTheYear as varchar(3)) +  '. New year''s eve is in '+ 
    cast (@untilNewYearsEve as varchar(3)) + ' days.'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This should work perfectly fine. 
while seeting the day of year you need to put @current date so it will work because you are trying to get a day from a @currentdate

    DECLARE
        @currentDate DateTime
            SET @currentDate = GETDATE();

    DECLARE @dayofyear datetime
    SET @dayofyear=DATEDIFF(day,STR(YEAR(@currentDate),4)+'0101',@currentDate)+1


    print('Hi! Today is '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @currentDate , 111) + '. ' + 'This is the day number '+ ' ' +  CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), @dayofyear) + 'of the year.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things a bit using DAYOFYEAR parameter in the DATEPART function if using SQL 2008 and above.  And you don't really need to declare a variable for the date.

**Sample Code:**

```
print('Hi! Today is '+ convert(varchar(10), getdate() , 111) + '. ' +  'This is the day number' + ' ' + convert(varchar, datepart(dayofyear, getdate()))) + ' of the year.'
```

**Results:**

```
Hi! Today is 2019/07/05. This is the day number 186 of the year.
```